# Sax Parser: processingInstruction() not called

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

maybe this is a n00b-question.

I try to parse an xml-file like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<test>
  <a></a>
</test>
```

with the following code:

```
public static void parse(File f) {
    final DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
        @Override
        public void processingInstruction(String target, String data) throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("Processing Instruction");
        }
    };
    SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().parse(f, handler);
}
```

I expect the output `"Processing Instruction"` to be printed on stdout. But this doesn't happen. Can somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From JavaDoc:

> A SAX parser must never report an XML declaration (XML 1.0, section 2.8) or a text declaration (XML 1.0, section 4.3.1) using this method.

As I understand it, the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` line will not be reported/catched by this method. Try to add another processing instruction in the xml code and feed it to the parser again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Another question then: Is it possible to find out if there is a valid xml declaration in the file?

Comment: @Martin: ISTR that it'll throw an exception if the declaration isn't valid.

Comment: In other words, a xml declaration is not a processing instruction and must not be reported by the parser as one.

Comment: @Vinko Unfortunately it doesn't throw an Exception if the declaration is missing...

Comment: @Martin: But it does if it's invalid, no?

Comment: What if one wants to copy a document yet alter it just a tiny bit and the

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="NOT_UTF8"?>

I mean, you should be able to catch that line as well!? Right? How could that be done?

Comment: The information in the XML declaration is only of use to the XML parser, it is of no use to the application, which is why it is not reported to the application. In particular, the application sees character data after decoding, so the original choice of encoding is irrelevant as far as the application is concerned.